# Como mapear retorno de um Value Object com Dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

Olá!

Estou com uma dúvida relacionado ao retorno de um objeto com um 'Value Object' já preenchido, exemplo:

Tenho a classe User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Email Email { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Email.cs

```
public class Email
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Em qualquer busca que faço com o Dapper o retorno do Email sempre vem nulo. Existe alguma forma de mapear o retorno do Dapper?

Obs. Os dados são persistidos em uma única tabela, não existe relacionamento.

Comment: [**Edite**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/290531/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o **código** ao invés de **imagem**! Leia: [**Postar código como imagem**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485).

Comment: Editado, obrigado.

Comment: Essa minha pergunta do StackOverflow En é bem parecida: [How to map a complex object using Spliton and Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273494/how-to-map-a-complex-object-using-spliton-and-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É simples

**Edit**, fiz sem o relacionamento da forma que você falou:

```
List<User> ret;
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    var sql =
        "select UserId, Name, Password, Email as Address from [User]";

    ret = db.Query<User, Email, User>(sql, (user, email) =>
    {
        user.Email = email;
        return user;
    }, splitOn: "Address").ToList();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifique a query se atende com as colunas do seu DB, no meu artigo explica detalhadamente!

No meu Github tem mais sobre:
https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/Dapper_ComplexObjects

Tenho também um artigo Sobre:
https://medium.com/@thiagoloureiro/dapper-objetos-complexos-5e5fae83caa7

Comment: Olá Thiago, obrigado por responder.

No meu caso não existe este relacionamento para o join, a tabela seria com as seguintes colunas:

'UserId, Name, Password e Email'

Como posso mapear para a coluna Email ser preenchida na Propriedade Email.Address?

Comment: Tentei utilizar Dommel + FluentMap mas também não tive sucesso. Alguma ideia? Obrigado

Comment: Leandro, porque você simplesmente não coloca a coluna email como string ? No Model digo..
  public string Email { get; set; }

E pronto.. vai resolver seu problema.. essa classe Email não faz sentido nenhum.